# sed or awk: search between two pattern, and, change word in second place

Tags: awk, sed

## FROM

```
White
Black
Green1
Red1
Yellow1
Blue
----
White
Black
Green2
Red2
Yellow2
Blue
----
White
Black
Green3
Red3
Yellow3
Blue
```

## TO

```
White
Black
Green1
Red1
Yellow1
Blue
----
White
Black
Green2
REDRED22
Yellow2
Blue
----
White
Black
Green3
Red3
Yellow3
Blue
```

Comment: can you give the file contents and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/Red2/REDRED22/'
```

Example:

```
sed 's/Red2/REDRED22/' redred 
White
Black
Green1
Red1
Yellow1
Blue
----
White
Black
Green2
REDRED22
Yellow2
Blue
----
White
Black
Green3
Red3
Yellow3
Blue
```

Where the original file looks like this:

```
cat redred 
White
Black
Green1
Red1
Yellow1
Blue
----
White
Black
Green2
Red2
Yellow2
Blue
----
White
Black
Green3
Red3
Yellow3
Blue
```

Comment: That works as long as there's only one `Red2` line in the file, or if all those lines are within the range of lines between the delimiters.

Comment: True, but it works for the example file. If that is indeed how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

The perl compatible generalized search should be as such:

```
(?<=Green2\n).*(?=(\n.*)+Yellow2)
```

I understand that the "before" and "after" patterns are Green2 and Yellow2 and the whole line after Green2 should be selected. This pattern works even if there are more lines before Yellow2. However due to escaping requirements at sed, this is very hard to implement there.

In perl you will do it like that:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=Green2\n).*(?=(\n.*)+Yellow2)/REDRED22/g' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late I know, but I couldn't resist the challenge of making this work with sed.

With the text placed in a file called redred:

```
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/(Green2\n)([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)(\nYellow2)/\1\2\2\3\3\4/g' redred
```

Uses [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) technique to deal with reading \n in to sed, and positional markers to break up and rebuild the target.

This also splits any target composed of text and number (e.g. Aubergine123) into the [[:alpha:]] and [[:digit:]] components and then rebuilds the target string the way the OP seemed to want (AubergineAubergine123123).